# Which software should I use to find out my former email addresses from browser installation files, found in old hard drives?

Tags: email, firefox, data-recovery, gmail, chromium

I had email addresses in the past, what I have completely forgotten about. I recently found 3 old hard drives that I knew were no good, went bad and I simply bought a new one. Lately I tried them and they all work. They all have old Linux installations, Arch Linux or PCLinuxOS, or at least my former HOME directories on them. The latter has Firefox, Chromium, and Opera browser installation or configuration files in them, profile files of the browsers from 2010-2015. From these I could somehow recover my old email addresses, which I have not used for a long time. Maybe even the password to them, because of course I can't remember that either. If only the email addresses could be extracted somehow that would be good.

I would prefer some Linux program / script, or portable windows app run with Wine, as I currently don't have Windows installation at my disposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give Nirsoft [WebBrowserPassView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html) a try.

It is aiming to extract usernames and passwords from stored browser profiles on disk and supports multiple web browsers. It works without installation and may also work on Wine.

WebBrowserPassView is free but closed source software.